Generate Signed URL with Prefix
I would like to create a signed URL for images in a directory inside a Google Cloud Storage bucket in Node.js. Looking at the SDK for Google Cloud Storage in Node.js you can easily create a signed url for a specific file. However it doesn't look like you can create a signed url with a prefix.
Looking at the Cloud CDN docs, it is however possible to create a signed URL with a prefix. This approach uses keys to generate the signed URL.
However, I'm using ADC to authenticate my service already for the Cloud Storage SDK.  I would like to continue using ADC and avoid creating keys and their corresponding service accounts.
Is there any way I can get a signing key from the Cloud Storage SDK to use instead of having to generate and manage different signed request keys for my backend?

Have a look at this Link1 and Link2.

@SandeepVokkareni Thanks for your comment. I have ADC successfully working already. Where I'm stuck is getting a key for use in signing a URL with prefix.

@Gabe I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further

signed URLs are created with the help of service account keys, which are actually RSA private keys. Generating signed urls requires a service account key file. You can not use this if you are using Application Default Credentials from the Google Cloud SDK.
Generating a signed url requires direct or indirect access to a private key.You need a private key to sign something. End-user credentials only have refresh tokens, so it's not possible to sign with them - however, you can impersonate a service account. See: (https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-impersonation) This may not be practical for your use case as you will have to grant users access to use that service account (letting them access all resources to which the service account has access).
Application Default Credentials (ADC) supports fetching tokens from the metadata service (Compute Engine, Cloud Run, Cloud Functions, etc). That means that the private key is not available to sign data. You can check more information here by John Hanley
There is also a  feature request raised for this Allow signing of URLs from default credentials, Which is still open and further progress can be tracked there.
